# Build dictionary for Apache concept mapper

Tags: uima

I have got an Excel file with two columns "Symbols" and "Synonyms" each having more than a million entries. I would like to convert excel data to a dictionary that is supported by Apache UIMA ConceptMapper. Is there any automated tool that can do this task?

I have attached a sample of excel data and format of Apache UIMA ConceptMapper.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QC9BU.png contains excel sample

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMItP.png contains ConceptMapper dictionary format

Comment: Hi Rakesh, I'm getting started with UIMA ConceptMapper and I've some troubles to configure it. Is your code on a public repo? Could you share it or perhaps how to configure the ConceptMapper? I've not found yet an example of usage which I can run to understand how it works. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I think you would need to convert the excel document, into a dictionary file. Where the excel cells are converted to keys.

I would suggest you look at [Apache POI](https://uima.apache.org/downloads/sandbox/DictionaryAnnotatorUserGuide/DictionaryAnnotatorUserGuide.html) for the excel conversion to the dictionary XML file, and for context to what I am talking about, I would look 
at this  [tutorial](https://uima.apache.org/downloads/sandbox/DictionaryAnnotatorUserGuide/DictionaryAnnotatorUserGuide.html).